# Default bluetooth device not allow to record from another device

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bluetooth, audio-recording, alsa, pulse-audio

I have already set the bluetooth device as default device for recording the audio. But I have add the another usb audio device for recording, the bluetooth device not allow the usb device to record the audio.

I want to record the audio from both the devices on same channel.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Also both the devices are on same audio channel.